# Checking nested Dart Map for nulls

Tags: dart

I have a dart `Map` I'm converting from json that itself contains nested maps.  Unfortunately, because this data comes from a web service I don't control, sometimes some of the nested values are in fact null.

For instance, if I have a value defined as follows:

```
data = json.decode(response.body) as Map;
  if (data["media_details"]["sizes"]["thumbnail"]["source_url"]
```

..sometimes the `["thumbnail"]` value will in fact be null.

Is there a concise way to check for null in these situations besides tediously walking down the Map and checking:

```
if (data["media_details"] != null) {
 if(data["media_details["sizes"] != null) {

//etc
```

I'm not sure if dart's null-aware operators are of use in situations like this, but am interested to learn if they are.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is currently no concise way to avoid repeated null checks for `[]` lookups. We hope to add that to the Dart language in a later version.

The best I can propose is:

```
 dynamic tmp;
 data = ((tmp = json["media_details"]) == null ? null 
        : (tmp = tmp["sizes"]) == null ? null
        : (tmp = tmp["thumbnail"]) == null ? null
        : tmp["source_url"];
```

That's ... still very ugly.

If you don't mind a little overhead, you can create a helper class:

```
class IndexWalker {
  dynamic value;
  IndexWalker(this.value);
  IndexWalker operator[](Object index) {
    if (value != null) value = value[index];
    return this;
  }
}
```

then you can do:

```
data = IndexWalker(json)["media_details"]["sizes"]["thumbnail"]["sources_url"].value;
```

Looks better, and a *good* optimizing compiler should be able to avoid the allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas here, much appreciated

Comment: @lrn Thanks for the answer! Any one on this "We hope to add that to the Dart language in a later version."?

Comment: That change is actually part of the null safety feature which will be released (at least in beta) Real Soon Now. Then you can write `data["media_details"]["sizes"]["thumbnail"]?["source_url"]` and the result is `null` if the thumbnail property is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use deep_pick package: https://pub.dev/packages/deep_pick

```dart
data = json.decode(response.body) as Map;
  if (pick(data, "media_details", "sizes", "thumbnail", "source_url")
```